# Image Centering issue over paragraph in Safari

Tags: css, image, safari, center

I can't seem to get the icons to align center over paragraphs in the Services section in Safari (it does center in all other browsers):

http://sidecarexecutivesupport.com/

Should be a simple css tweak but it is escaping me. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `text-align: center;` and `display: block;` into the `[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"]` selector in your styles. (I tested this out in the inspector and it appeared to work)

As an additional recommendation, the `<i>` tag isn't really meant to be used in the way you are using it.. I would recommend replacing it with something a little more semantic, perhaps a span? Also, rather than putting the graphic in with the styles with `:before { content }`, why not simply place it directly into the html, inside the tag you have created for it? This could make some of your styling a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

as text-align:center seems to be a good idea, it is TEXT align, meaning it is not designed to align block elements. That's why i'd suggest to append attribute "text-align:center" to the parent block (class "one-fourth").

It will work quite good without anything else... and since all the other text below should be also centered, it is just what you need.

Comment: Then why don't you check the answer? :-)